# Determine which button was tapped on system alert

Tags: ios, storekit

I am presenting `SKStoreReviewController.requestReview()` and I want to have a `boolean` in `UserDefaults` which I would make `true` in case the user taps on Cancel.

Is there a way to determine if cancel was tapped considering this is a OS alert?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn’t a way to access which button was selected. I’m curious why you would you need this functionality? The OS will decide if the user should be shown the alert depending on a few factors including when the user last left a review or canceled.

Apple Developer Site:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skstorereviewcontroller/2851536-requestreview

> Although you should call this method when it makes sense in the user
>   experience flow of your app, the actual display of a rating/review
>   request view is governed by App Store policy. Because this method may
>   or may not present an alert, it's not appropriate to call it in
>   response to a button tap or other user action.

Comment: Yes, I know the API decides when to show the alert, but I wanted to implement something like if the user taps on "Cancel" to never show/request the alert again or to not show/request for a long time.

Comment: There is no way to control this yourself unfortunately. But the API does however do an awesome job of this anyway. From what I've observed it doesn't show the user a review alert again for a few versions or some long period of time. Not sure exactly how they work out if it should be shown but it's probably better to let them decide as it would be based on the users usage patterns (Maybe even using AI...)